# Create a subtitle with titling for use with fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr, titling

I'm new to LaTeX and am trying to create a subtitle for a document. I'm using the `titling` package because it propagates values like the document title, author name, etc. even after `maketitle` is called. I want to use the subtitle as part of the header I've defined using the `fancyhdr` package. While I've been able to create and format the subtitle as I like I cannot figure out how to make its value available for use later in the document. Here is a minimal working example of what I have been able to build so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%define subtitle command
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
    \posttitle{%
        \par\end{center}
        \begin{center}\Large#1\end{center}
        \vskip0.5em%
    }
}

\title{Paper Title}
\subtitle{Paper Sub-title}
\author{Author Name}
\date{\today}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\theauthor}
\lhead{\thetitle} % I want to replace this with the subtitle defined above

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I've tried exporting the subtitle value by adding `\def \thesubtitle#1%` in the new `subtitle` command and then using`\lhead{\thesubtitle}` in the preamble to generate the header I want but I get no output from it. I'm sure I'm missing something simple and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Like this: `\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%                                                     
  \newcommand\thesubtitle{#1}%                                                  
  \posttitle{%                                                                  
    \par\end{center}                                                            
  \begin{center}\Large#1\end{center}                                            
  \vskip0.5em%                                                                  
}}`?

Comment: @jon Would you like to add an answer?